# jQuery, click event doesn't fire

Tags: jquery, ajax, click

My problem was (because I solved it, but I don't know why it worked):
I had two `'span'` tags inside my `DOM` with the same `CSS` class.
One span was added via AJAX request.
I was trying to fire click event on them using:

```
$('.css class').on('click', function ...
```

but `'span'` tag that was added second (AJAX) didn't produce click event.
When I've changed above line to:

```
jQuery('body').on('click', '.css class', function(e){...
```

everything started to work as it should.
I don't know why.

Comment: You can read here: https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/

Answer (score 1):

Use event delegation:

```
$('body').on('click','.css-class',function(){
 // your code goes here.
});
```

Remember not to have spaces in the class. Otherwise you'll be targeting `<class>` which is under the `.css`

### on()

> Event handlers are bound only to the currently selected elements; they
>   must exist on the page at the time your code makes the call to .on().
>   To ensure the elements are present and can be selected, perform event
>   binding inside a document ready handler for elements that are in the
>   HTML markup on the page. If new HTML is being injected into the page,
>   select the elements and attach event handlers after the new HTML is
>   placed into the page. Or, use delegated events to attach an event
>   handler, as described next.
>
> Delegated events have the advantage that they can process events from
>   descendant elements that are added to the document at a later time. By
>   picking an element that is guaranteed to be present at the time the
>   delegated event handler is attached, you can use delegated events to
>   avoid the need to frequently attach and remove event handlers....

[Read more](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)

Comment: Thanks:). It explains everything.